# Consulta de cep muito lerdo

Tags: php, json, google-maps

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
include 'conn.php';
    $query = $mysql_adv->query("SELECT * FROM dados");
    while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
        $url  = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=";
        $url .= $row['cep_adv']."&destinations=".$_GET['cep'];
        $url .= "&language=pt&mode=car&key=AIzaSyDL6_dJ-Mbi_03_g6lHhWibxY22Z2UeYZQ";
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
    }
```

estou fazendo uma consulta com 30 ceps e esta muito lerdo o carregamento! cerca de 1 minuto, oque posso fazer?

Comment: Explique melhor como funciona. Você está usando API da Google? O que deveria acontecer? O que você já tentou? etc...

Answer (score 1):

Contando que vc está utilizando um serviço público, não há muito o que fazer a não ser adquirir um serviço privado ou ter sua própria base de dados de CEP.

O site do Google recebe muitas requisições, possívelmente eles não disponibilizam muitos recursos computacionais para serviços abertos como esta consulta de cep.